# NFA for the star of a language (01 U 001 U 010)*

Tags: theory, automata, computation-theory, nfa

Problem from page 5 of [this pdf](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Exiangxiao/cs1502/recitation11.pdf).

Give an NFA that recognizing the language (01 U 001 U 010)*
[image]

I think this is wrong because there should be an additional start state (accepting) going to state 1 for the empty string in the beginning. That's how the closure under star is proved in Sipser. Am I missing something?

Here's what I think it should be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you correctly understood the star in the first pattern, but the NFA is correct. `x*` represents the pattern `x` repeated 0 or more times.

State 1 is the start state. You know it can match an empty string because the start state is also the end state. Another way you can think of it is that the arrow on the left indicates that there is an implicit start state which accepts an empty string and transitions to state 1.

Assuming I remember my classes correctly:

- The first arrow on the left indicates that when started you enter state 1.
- The double circle indicates that state 1 is also a valid end state.
- ε represents an empty string. This is part of what makes this finite automata non-deterministic. For example if you were in state 5, there is no one single correct response and a single string may be able to traverse more than one list of states.

Comment: I have added what I think should be the answer in my question.

Comment: @learner Another way you can think of it is that NFAs are extensions of DFAs that allow for state transitions of ε (and other non-deterministic transitions). However since an empty string can be matched by a DFA, how would you represent a language containing only the empty string without using ε? The answer is since there are no characters consumed there is no state transition. By definition, a DFA defines the set of strings for a language where the final state reached is an end state. With this definition there is no issue when no transitions are performed.

Comment: I followed the construction of closure under star provided in Sipser's Theory of Computation. Can you explain how we could arrive at the given solution from my solution?

Comment: @learner They are both identical in function, but your solution could be made more concise. Since the only transitions into 1 in your diagram are from end states and they all consume an empty string as their transitions, then it would be fair to make 1 an end state as well. You can prove this by showing that the only strings that will end in state 1 are strings within the language followed by the empty string. Or in other words, just strings in the language since `xε=x`. From there end-states can be changed to regular states if they have a transition of ε to an end state.

Comment: Then why to ever include the extra initial state with the empty string? Why did Sipser include that initial state in his book while proving closure under star? I watched MIT OCW's lecture by the man himself but he didn't really justify it.

Comment: Some people like to make an explicit state for the start state separate from the rest of the automata. It may vary depending on who is teaching the course, but they all mean the same thing. I imagine he also felt that separating it out would help make it easier to conceptualize the state transitions for beginners and introduce the concept. However when used in a larger automata, it can be important to use less states to stop your diagram from getting cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good practice to include a new start state as you mentioned but for this particular problem,it is unnecessary.A new start state is used to prevent the machine from producing unexpected strings since the initial start state may be pointed by arrows coming from non-accept states.But there is no such transition arrow in this particular example and introducing a new start state is unnecessary.